# Puppeteer error in different OS when using evaluate

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using a nodejs package to scrape product data off aliexpress.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const Variants = require('./variants');
const Feedback = require('./feedback');

async function AliexpressProductScraper(productId, feedbackLimit) {
  const FEEDBACK_LIMIT = feedbackLimit || 10;
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  /** Scrape the aliexpress product page for details */
  await page.goto(`https://www.aliexpress.com/item/${productId}.html`);

  const aliExpressData = await page.evaluate(() => runParams);
  // console.log(aliExpressData);


  const data = aliExpressData.data;
```

The code works fine on my mac, but not on the server. On server when I run it I get the following error

```
Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: runParams is not defined
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:8
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (/home/forge/scraper/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:122:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
      -- ASYNC --
    at ExecutionContext.<anonymous> (/home/forge/scraper/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
    at DOMWorld.evaluate (/home/forge/scraper/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:112:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
      -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (/home/forge/scraper/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.evaluate (/home/forge/scraper/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:833:43)
    at Page.<anonymous> (/home/forge/scraper/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
    at AliexpressProductScraper (/home/forge/scraper/scraper/src/aliexpressProductScraper.js:14:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

For some reason, it is not throwing runParams not defined on macos
Package that I'm using https://github.com/sudheer-ranga/aliexpress-product-scraper

Comment: make sure you the same puppeteer version in both environments. you can use https://github.com/buildkite/docker-puppeteer to make sure puppeteer is the same regardless where is run

Comment: I looked into github and don't know where `runParams` defined.

Comment: Thanks for checking it Manh Le. Even I checked and couldn't find it. But it seems to work fine on macos for some reason.

Comment: @rajathans since you're not defining the variable, try making it an argument in the arrow function. Like so: (runparams) => { runparams}